# Why android in tablets unable to inflate MaterialToolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I am having `MaterialToolbar` inside a fragment that is loaded by `BottomNavigationView` in the main activity.

I added `MaterialToolbar` inside the `onViewCreated` of the fragment to ensure the component is inflated from the XML layout as the following code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    toolbar = (MaterialToolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.WajadtuhaHomeTopAppBar);

    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.welcome)+" "+prefs.getString("username",""));
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home);
    NavigationView navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that is is working from the android phones but return null point exception if I run it from the android tables as the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.leamra.wajadtuha, PID: 4949
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.leamra.wajadtuha/com.leamra.wajadtuha.Activity.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.leamra.wajadtuha.Fragments.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.java:421)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:501)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6994)
```

here is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Fragments.HomeFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment_home">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/WajadtuhaHomeTopAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="Welcome"
            android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24_1"
            android:background="@color/orange_900"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarCenturyGothicBold" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dashboard_top"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_progressbars_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle1"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ProgressBar

                    android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progress="50"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
                    android:secondaryProgress="100"
                    android:scaleY="1.5"
                    android:scaleX="1.5"
                    >
                </ProgressBar>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/distance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:text="@string/km_0"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_highway"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle2"

                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                >

                <ProgressBar

                    android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar2"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progress="50"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
                    android:secondaryProgress="100"
                    android:scaleY="1.5"
                    android:scaleX="1.5"
                    >
                </ProgressBar>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/alerts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_40"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications"

                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:text="@string/_10_nalerts"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/VehStatinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:text="@string/_10_vehicles_4_online_2_parking_4_offline"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_progressbars_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/live_view_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_live"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_active"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_round_location_on"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/Live_View"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/playback_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/live_view_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_playback"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_active"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_replay_24"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/playBack"
                android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_notifications_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/live_view_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_notification"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_tire" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_500"
                android:text="@string/notifications"
                android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:layout_below="@+id/live_view_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_alert"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_active"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/alerts"
                android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/playback_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_vdeo"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_active"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_videocam_or"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/live_video"
                android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_40"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/top_notification"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noalerts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_notifications"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_black"/>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/home_navigation_items"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

These are some of the dependencies I have:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Comment: are you sure you haven't got a specfic layout for the screen config i.e `layout-sw600dp` folder, that doesn't match the standard layout file?

Comment: omg. yes. there is layout-sw600dp folder. But I do not know what it is for. should I delete it?

Comment: I think I got it! it is for other screen sizes!

Comment: depending on the environment an app is running in different resources can be chosen - it allows for configuration based on different devices, for layouts this can mean different layouts based on screen sizes / orientation etc .. if their is an existing file, better to just amend it by adding your toolbar as I'm guessing it has some visual differences, maybe margins are different from that of the default layout

Comment: I removed the folder `layout-sw600dp` completely but still I get the same error when running in the tablet

Comment: there could be `layout-sw720dp` folder, or `layout-sw600dp-land` folder or `layout-sw720dp-land` folder - all these and configurable, valid layout folders you might also have